# Modernizr is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modernizr

I've included the Modernizr Touch Events detection to my project (only left the rest out to keep it light as possible).

I use it to set different Google Maps JS options as following:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 52.022322, lng: 4.209055};
    if( Modernizr.touchevents ) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            center: myLatLng,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: false,
        });

    } else {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            center: myLatLng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: true,
        });
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Duijnisveld Kasconstructies',
    });
  }
</script>
```

I've included this script in my page-contact.php file which displays the contact page on my Wordpress project.

Whenever I view the [page](http://duijnisveld.wpengine.com/contact/) I see no map and note the following error in my console:
`(index):235 Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined`

What am I missing here?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you including Modernizr *before* the rest of your code?

Comment: ahh shoot, that was the issue. Silly me. If you want the credit you should post an answer as you were first, otherwise I'll accept Agu V's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling Modernizr before theme-min.js which is where you are defining it.

You should move your code below this line.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://duijnisveld.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/duijnisveld-kascontructies/scripts/min/theme-min.js?ver=4.5.3"></script>
```