# how to move menu border on hover-2

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement this code from codepen https://codepen.io/Wilhearts/pen/LcdJr

But it gives me following error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined

I tried and added following scripts at the end of HTML file after main.js file and  before closing body tag:

```
        <script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But still didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

No, it didn't help. i have following scripts :

```
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also added this script :   <script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>

Comment: you need to put your actual code and reference here to let us check the actual exception cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Modernizr before .js which is where you are defining it.

You should move your code below the reference line.

**[Duplicate As Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082814/modernizr-is-not-defined)**

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

jquery>>>modernizr>>>main.js the right order.

Comment: No, it didn't help.

Comment: Happens! Good luck with the project :)